# Determine coefficients of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\cdot\frac{(x-2\pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$ determine $c_2$

Let $x=2\pi$, then:
$$c_2=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\cdot\frac{(x-2\pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\cdot\frac{(2k)(2k-1)(x-2\pi)^{2k-2}}{(2k)!} \\ =\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\cdot\frac{(x-2\pi)^{2k-2}}{(2k-2)!}\\\stackrel{x=2\pi}{=}-1$$

However, my answer file says $c_2=-\frac{1}{2}$. Could anyone point out where I made a mistake?

Comment: Why the second derivative rather than $\dfrac{1}{2!}$ times the second derivative?

Comment: Surely the result depends on $a$? See my answer.

Comment: @Holograph: As TonyK pointed out in his answer the result depends on $a$. As your answer file states that $c_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$ I would suspect that  you forgot to mention that $a$ is fixed (with $a \in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$). If $a \neq 2\pi$ then my post (which you accepted) does not fully answer the question, so you should unaccept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As TonyK pointed out in his answer the result depends on $a$ and is given by $-\frac{\cos(a)}{2}$. As your answer file gives the solution $-\frac{1}{2}$ is assume that you forgot to mention that $a$ is actually fixed (with $a \in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. In my answer below I assumed that $a = 2\pi$.

---

The mistake you make is that if $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x-a)^n$ in a neighborhood of $a$, then $c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$. So you still need to divide your result by $2! = 2$.

Another way to see this would be to use $a = 2\pi$ and
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(x-2\pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!}
 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} (x-a)^{2k}
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x-a)^n
$$
with
$$
 c_n =
 \begin{cases}
  \frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{n!} & \text{if $n$ is even}, \\
  0                     & \text{if $n$ is odd}.
 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: This is wrong $-$ the result depends on $a$. See my answer.

Comment: @TonyK: My mistake, I somehow assumed that $a = 2\pi$. I asked the question asker to unaccept my post.

Answer (score 1):

$c_2$ is the coefficient of $(x-2\pi)^2$, which in your sum is
$$
(-1)^{2/2} \frac{1}{2!} = \frac{-1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\cdot\frac{(x-2\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \cos x - 1$$

So

$$\begin{align}
1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n & = \cos(x+a)\\
& = \cos a \cos x - \sin a \sin x \\
& = \cos a\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} - \sin a\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align}
$$

Equating coefficients of $x^2$ gives

$$c_2 = -\frac12 \cos a$$